# Spring Boot & Security OAuth2 Token Access issue

Tags: spring-security, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I have got some problem about when I wanna get "access token", I using spring security in my project

**WebSecurity Config**

I set user in memory for authentication in this class and I am using memory token

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Bean
public static BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public static class ApiLoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable().antMatcher("/oauth/token").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();


    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("sencer").password("123").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();

    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

I define client_id and client_secret in configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) for API security

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

static final String CLIEN_ID = "devglan-client";
static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "$2a$04$P5rlxlVjNvO2VROrwktmrevMV/XQr7LSkF6aJveL4R7k/0SAR8VQu";
static final String GRANT_TYPE = "password";
static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
static final String TRUST = "trust";
static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1*60*60;
static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6*60*60;

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

    configurer
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
            .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
            .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
}

}
```

[image: Response error when i posted]

> I send grant_type , client_id , client_secret , username and password correctly but not response "access token" on API

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable basic authentication for default Token Endpoint, then preferable way is to allow form authentication for client `allowFormAuthenticationForClients()`

Try removing this http security configuration
`http.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable().antMatcher("/oauth/token").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();`

and configure this

```
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
  }
```